# Inequality operators and sorting in Python

Tags: python

I have a collection (list) of objects. I want to be able to sort the objects without having to provide a callback (lambda function) to `sorted()` but instead, by implementing functions that could be used to ascertain strict (in)equality between objects of the same type - ala C++.

The `__eq__()` function implemented on a class allows equality checks. I can't seem to find any similar functions to implement `<` and `>`

How may I implement this in Python?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Via [`__lt__()` and `__gt__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__).

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization

You're looking for

```
__lt__() and __gt__()
```

(it's down just a tad under that link).